# MacOS Monterey: Set Notification Center notifications to expire?

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey

I find notifications somewhat useful, but I hate managing them in Notification Center. They stack up uselessly and must be dismissed by hand. Can Notification Center notifications be configured to *expire* after some time? Note: I don't mean the difference between "banners" and "alerts," I want the alerts to go away from the Notification Center on their own after some length of time. I also don't mean the ability to turn off notifications per application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this old thread - looks, that it doesn't and I'm afraid it didn't change anything since then.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5053666

> Nope.  There's a limit on the number of items in a section, but they don't "expire" and disappear. You could click that little X and be done with 3 of them right there

Comment: @agarza ok, updated and added the related answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some AppleScript that works for me on MacOS Monterey.
Open the Script Editor, paste this and run the code (<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>).

```
on closeNotifs(numTimes)
    repeat numTimes times
        try
            tell application "System Events" to tell application process "NotificationCenter"
                set boxes to groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
                set numBoxes to count boxes
                repeat with i from numBoxes to 1 by -1
                    try
                        perform item 1 of (actions of item i of boxes whose name starts with "Name")
                    end try
                end repeat
            end tell
        end try
    end repeat
end closeNotifs

closeNotifs(2)
log "done"
```

Instead of `whose name starts with "Name"`you may use `whose name description is "Close"` but I don't have English settings. I think this should work for any language.

I haven't solved the problem that the last notification is not closed automatically, so I basically run it twice.

This has been a PITA for so long.

Now to get it to work as a shortcut, you might have to create a unix script with

```
#!/usr/bin/osascript

on closeNotifs(numTimes)
    repeat numTimes times
        try
            tell application "System Events" to tell application process "NotificationCenter"
                set boxes to groups of UI element 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1
                set numBoxes to count boxes
                repeat with i from numBoxes to 1 by -1
                    try
                        perform item 1 of (actions of item i of boxes whose name starts with "Name")
                    end try
                end repeat
            end tell
        end try
    end repeat
end closeNotifs

closeNotifs(2)
log "done"
```

Save this as a file e.g.
`/usr/local/bin/stfu`
then set it as an executable
`chmod +x /usr/local/bin/stfu`